# DOM loading and plain HTML appending

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Normally, I use `domReady()` functions (either jQuery's or hand made ones) when I want to execute some code after I'm sure the Page's DOM was fully loaded (99% of cases is initialization code).

Now I'm currently having to append some HTML template inside a DIV element, but after that I need to get some elements that were added to it and manipulate them (change texts, attach events, set validations messages and masks etc.).

```
div.innerHTML += htmlTemplate; // Template which has the "someInput" input
var someInput = document.getElementById('someInput');
```

The thing is: Is it safe to assume that the `input` was loaded into DOM? After I append the HTML to the DIV, do I have to send the code that relies on the new DOM elements as a callback to the `domReady` function?

```
div.innerHTML += htmlTemplate;
domReady(function(){
    var someInput = document.getElementById('someInput');
    // ...
});
```

Technically speaking... Every time plain HTML is added to elements, does the DOM enter into the [loading state](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_readystate.asp)?

-- EDIT

Here's the domReady() function I'm using:

```
function domReady(f) {
    /in/.test(document.readyState) ? setTimeout('domReady('+f+')', 9) : f();
}
```

PS: I needed a simple/short/not-api-dependent function, so I came across this one in SE a while ago.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: DOM event 'load' is triggered only once when it is loaded for the first time. More information : http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-load

Comment: Actually, my current "domReady()" function is relying on the document's readystate... I'll add it to the question.

Comment: Look at [Event developer guide MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Events)

Comment: I don't get it... Do I have to add a "ready" event handler to the DIV I'm adding HTML to?

Comment: Appending HTML like that (`innerHTML += more_stuff;`) causes the browser to re-parse *all* the content of the affected container.  It's not the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: Since this container is empty at that time, I guess it shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Every time plain HTML is added to elements, does the DOM enter into the loading state?

No, it doesn't. You can count on the elements being there right after the `innerHTML=` call ends. Check out [this jsbin](http://jsbin.com/evOYEye/1) where I spend 1 second adding `<li>` elements using `innerHTML`, and check every time that the previous elements are there using `.querySelectorAll`.

Setting `element.innerHTML` is synchronous: The browser stops whatever it is doing to update the DOM accordingly (which doesn't mean that the page is visually updated, as can be seen on the example I linked to), and control doesn't return to your code until it is done.

---

Example of manipulations in a detached DOM node:

```
var tempDiv = document.createElement("div");
tempDiv.innerHTML = getTemplateSomehow();

// Manipulate a button inside the template,
// even though it is not in the DOM yet
var button = tempDiv.querySelector("button");
button.style.color = "red";
button.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("button clicked");
});

// Append all children from the parsed template into the DOM
var child;
var target = document.body;

// Keep moving tempDiv's children to the target until it is empty
while(child = tempDiv.firstChild) {
  target.appendChild(child);
}
```

Working example: http://jsbin.com/isuLeMi/1/edit

Comment: Thanks! Where I can find the confirmation (docs) that `element.innerHTML` appending is synchronous in terms of DOM loading?

Comment: I've tried looking for this statement explicitly, but couldn't find any documentation. However, I think it is implicit in the API, since there are no events or callbacks that can be attached to the modification

Comment: I am worried because the template I'm appending could be big, and weird things could happen if I'm relying on non loaded elements. Do you have an idea on how to test this, then?

Comment: Maybe you could try a test similar to mine, but with bigger templates... As an alternative, you might want to do your manipulations on a detached DOM node, to help the browser doing it with more performance. Can you add examples of what kind of transformation you need to do afterwards to your question?

Comment: Until now, fields error messages, validation masks, button events attaching etc.

Comment: And you're not using jQuery? Seems brave :) Added a small example, please take a look

Comment: I'm working on a pluggable widget, I guess you understand the scenario now (also why I can't use jQuery and I needed a simple `domReady()` function). Well, I must append all template in a pre-defined DIV, so how could I work with this detached DIV and only append all of it's contents on the page's DIV?

Comment: You just need to change the `document.body` on the penultimate line to your div

Comment: Oh, I understood the tempDiv.firstChild mechanic now, sorry. I'll test it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about onload event in domReady then this event is fired only one time 
on page life cycle when the document is entire loaded by the browers, to observe specific elements you will need add 'change' listeners to this elements.

Comment: "The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value." [change MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/change)

Comment: Sorry but I don't see how does it apply to this situation.

Answer (score 0):

The thing is, that the browser stops executing anything when javascript runs. That means when you add a div with the id "Example" you can't access it in the same event as you have added it.
However there is (in my opinion) clean workaround for this:

Execute the part of the code that accesses the dynamic created content via 
`window.setTimout(func, 0);`

This allows the browser to execute other stuff (like rendering, dom editing, etc...) and execute your code that accesses it just after the browser has finished his queue of work.